# cannot round decimals to two decimal places in R

Tags: r, floating-point

I have tried different functions to round decimals to two digits, such as `format()`, `formatC()`,`signif()` and `round()`. None of them can truly round all decimals to two decimal places.

For example, my data frame DF has three columns: Index, PDF and CDF:

```
   Index          PDF          CDF
1  -1.00 8.306360e-07 8.306360e-09
2  -0.99 8.332774e-07 1.663913e-08
3  -0.98 8.411712e-07 2.505085e-08
4  -0.97 8.542267e-07 3.359311e-08
5  -0.96 8.722951e-07 4.231606e-08
6  -0.95 8.951719e-07 5.126778e-08
7  -0.94 9.226012e-07 6.049380e-08
8  -0.93 9.542808e-07 7.003660e-08
9  -0.92 9.898679e-07 7.993528e-08
10 -0.91 1.028986e-06 9.022514e-08
...
...
...
```

The column `Index` is a vector, from -1.00 to 10.00.The difference between any consecutive elements is 0.01. It implies that `unique(diff(Index))` should return only one value and it must be 0.01. However, `unique(diff(Index))` can return several 0.01.

My purpose is to compute the difference between any two elements of the column`CDF`, and these two elements are selected by indicating their `Index`. For example,

```
a<-DF$CDF[DF$Index==(r+dr)];

b<-DF$CDF[DF$Index==(r-dr)];

res<-a-b;
```

`r` is any number of `Index`, `dr`can be 0.01, 0.02 or 0.03. However, since some elements of `Index` cannot be rounded to 2 digits (although they all look like that), therefore I cannot compute `res` for any r and dr.

How should I tackle this problem? Thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: If you know they're definitely unique, why not first ensure sort order and then create an integer index `1:length(DF$Index)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point in the function `unique`, the function will have to test, if two Index-Diffs are the same and it will likely do this with `==`. However, comparing floating point values with `==` is rarely a good idea. Use your favourite searching page with "floating point equal" or "floating point comparison" or read at http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ about this problem, which you should always be aware of, not only for this specific problem.

My advice in this case: Multiply you index values by 100, convert them to integers and `==` (and thereby `unique`) will work perfectly alright with integers.

### Edit

Thanks to the comments by @hrbrmstr below I found, that you need to not only `as.integer` but to also `round` the numbers, as illustrated in the following code

```
#wrong result due to floating point arithmetic
unique(diff(seq(-1,1,0.1)))

# multiple steps towards a working solution
seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
10*seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
as.integer(round(10*seq(-1, 1, 0.1)))
diff(as.integer(round(10*seq(-1, 1, 0.1))))
unique(diff(as.integer(round(10*seq(-1, 1, 0.1))))) # works!
```

Comment: The OP has not given an mcve ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) that produces the the problem with the seemingly same but truely unique values, so I cannot answer that with code parallel to his. Multiplying by 100 and converting can be done with `function(x) as.integer(x*100)`.

Comment: you really can't use `seq(-1.00, 10.00, 0.01)` to show them?

Comment: I corrected and updated my answer and added some example code. I learned, that one has to combine `as.integer` and `round` as `as.integer` apparently does not do the rounding, I expected it to do. Thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: I appreciate your help!! @Bernhard

Comment: You're welcome. However, consider the comment from @hrbrmstr under your question, to introduce a totally different integer index starting from one, as well.  Although I like in my proposal that you keep more resemblance with the original Index, you can construct his index with very little and easy-to-read code whereas my last line of code is considerably ugly.